# VBA setting new filter of pivot table in another file based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I m a newbie to vba and need your help: I managed to create a code which opens a different excel file called "test" when making a double click in any cell of column H. So far so good.

In the file "test" there is a pivot table and I want to set the filter there with the respective value of the first file's C column where I made the double click on the H column. For example, if I make a double click on H30, I want to copy the value of C30, if I double click on H50, I want to copy the value of C50 and insert it as a new filter in the pivot table of the "test" file. Therefore I created the "test" macro. Hope that makes sense lol.

That is my current code, which always takes the C24 value and inserts it in the filter.

Many thanks guys!

```
Sub test()
'
' test Makro
'

'
    Range("C24").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("test.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields( _
        "[Abfrage].[D_JL_NR].[D_JL_NR]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Abfrage].[D_JL_NR].&[15109]")
    Windows("test.xlsx").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: You can work with Range(Target.Offset(0, -2).Address).Select to geht the value with the disired offset.

This will get the address of the cell that is at the same row but 2 columns to the left (adjust offset to your liking)

Comment: Thanks, but If i replace "Range("C24").Select" with "Range(Target.Offset(0, -2).Address).Select" with that, run time error 404 object required occurs. Did I do something wrong? :/

Comment: You'll want to run this snippet in the double-click event as otherwise "Target" won't have an object to find the address of. (also, you will get runtime error 1004 when the offset will be out of bounds)

Comment: Ok im too noobish for that lol: my current code is this atm for the doubleblick:
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Excel.Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H1:H3300")) Is Nothing Then
   Cancel = True
   finaloeffnenneu
      
End If
End Sub

Where should I insert this one? I usually dont use VBA so thats the reason Im pretty inexperienced :(

Comment: I'll put that reply into an answer for formatting reasons then

Answer (score 1):

From the comments on the questions.

You'll want to hand over the cell's value from the event to the macro you are working with. This will look something like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Call Test(Target.Offset(0, -5).Value)
End Sub
```

and the macro that's starting you'll want like this:

```
Sub Test(str As String)

    MsgBox str

End Sub
```

The value you clicked minus 5 columns will be handed over and available as "str" in the other macro

Above example will give you a message with what the selection is, but from there you can put "str" into wherever you need it

Comment: Thanks a lot, and if I want to enter this "str" into the others file's "pivotTable3" where the field of the pivot table's filter is "JL_NR", what I gotta do? Hope that is clear. Tysm!

Comment: As I haven't worked with pivot-filters THAT much until now so I need to double check: You need toFilter the field "JL_NR" onto the value you double clicked, right?

If so below code will make "str" in the field visible

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("FieldName")
        .PivotItems(str).Visible = True
    End With

Comment: Yes thanks a lot, but actually I need to filter on the value which is 5 columns left to the field I double clicked in file "test.xlsx", e.g. I click on H26 and want the value of C26. The pivot table (named pivotTable3") is saved in the file "pivot.xlsx". Where do I have to enter this code now? in the file "test.xlsx" or in the "pivot.xlsx". Many thanks!

Comment: You can put all into the "test" workbook.
At some Point you are Opening the pivot.xlsx and as opened workbooks usually are set as Active the code will continue to run in the new workbook (and therefore apply to objects in there)

Comment: Ok, I think I gotta surrender it doesnt work lol. Could you please help me with the code maybe? These are the things I need: 1. If I doubleclick in the column H on any cell from H4:H7 I want the file "pivot.xlsx" to be opened and use the respective number of the column B to be the new filter in the pivot table of the file "pivot.xlsx". For example, If I click on H4 "X", I want that the value of C4 "200" is the new filter in the pivot table of "pivot.xlsx". My files: https://easyupload.io/m/akb8g0 . That would mean a lot to me!

Answer (score 0):

```
Range(Target.Offset(0, -2).Address).Select ' Select Cell -2 rows from click
```